# Upload image from Android to Database MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, xml

i'm tring to upload an image from an Android application to a database managed by MySQL. From Java i wrote this code.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
String encoded = Utility.encodeToBase64(bitmap);
jsonObject.put(AVATAR, encoded);

sendTo(MY_URL_ON_DB, jsonObject.toString());

public static String encodeToBase64(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, baos);
    String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(baos.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);

    return encoded;
}


public static String sendTo(String url, String json) {
    String output = null;
    try {
        OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).post(body).build();
        Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();

        output = response.body().string();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return output;
}
```

When i execute the app and try to start the upload of an image, i get TimeOutException error from OkHttp library. How can i solve?

Maybe the problem could be that the JSONObject (encoded Base64 string, in particular) is too much big?